# how to cleanup launchctl when removing app

Tags: macos, launchctl

I writing an app for Mac, one of it's components is a launchctl agent that runs in background.

As mac apps are removed by dragging to trash (I can understand this logic but takes getting used to after years of windows dev'ing), I'm wondering is there anything I can do to cleanup after myself when the user removes the app?

specifically the running background process and its .plist file.

Edit:
After some more thinking about the issue, I have an idea to put a listener on the background process file, get notified if it's deleted, then remove itself from launchctl, delete plist and kill itself. can this work?

Comment: Write an installer with the option to uninstall the app and its components.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the suggestion, I was hopping to avoid uninstallers as they are not standard on mac, any thoughts if the idea I wrote in the edit is possible?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?